# Can't see artifact ui in mlflow dashboard

Tags: mlflow

mlflow server 
--host 0.0.0.0 
--port 5000 
--backend-store-uri sqlite:////tmp/test.db 
--artifacts-destination s3://mlflow 
--serve-artifacts

Using minio as S3
And env. Variable as secret key & access key

#mlflow #artifactui #proxyartifact[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3h0B.png)

Comment: dilip@dilip-Precision-3530:~$ mlflow server --host 0.0.0.0 --port 5000 --backend-store-uri sqlite:////tmp/test.db --artifacts-destination file:/home/dilip/artifacts --serve-artifacts
2022/08/09 11:02:14 INFO mlflow.store.db.utils: Creating initial MLflow database tables...
2022/08/09 11:02:16 INFO mlflow.store.db.utils: Updating database tables
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.


Still artifact is not visibale in UI

Answer (score 0):

Once you correctly configured the artifacts-destination, the logged artifacts should be logged to the destination. You should see artifacts in the experiment detail.

I think you should check the logging function use local file storage first by passing `file:/path/to/artifacts/dir`.
I have all artifacts logged to the destination with the following command:

```bash
mlflow server
--host 0.0.0.0
--port 5000
--backend-store-uri sqlite:///mlflow.db
--artifacts-destination file:/home/user/artifacts
--serve-artifacts
```